# Creating a directory from command line on a DD-WRT router

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have a problem with creating a directory with a DD-WRT router. The router's DD-WRT firmware version is v24-sp2. I enter the command mkdir /jffs/www and I dont get anything returned that would say directory created. I try listing the directory and the www folder is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly JFFS just isn't enabled. In the DD-WRT admin interface, go to the **Administration** > **Management** tab. Check whether JFFS2 is enabled in the JFFS2 Support section. If it isn't, enable it and click the **Save** button. You'll probably need to restart the router for the change to take effect.